# How to activate Completion Insight in JDeveloper IDE

Tags: java, ide, javadoc, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Can someone please direct me to how i can activate Completion Insight in JDeveloper(12) IDE  so that i can get help from Javadoc and/or ADF Faces in **editor window** 
[image]

**EDIT**

With `CTRL+ALT+SPACE` or `CTRL+ALT` i get the image below. Now how can i bind the javadoc to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug pending for completion inside. See https://java.net/jira/browse/ADFEMG-154

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc-Documentation (Press Alt and Mouse Over on a class or method in java source code)

find more here:

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/user.1112/e17455/working_jdev.htm

and

> http://multikoop.blogspot.se/2010/01/jdeveloper-11g-know-ides-coding.html

and

> http://sureshkrishna.com/blog/?p=521